# System.Socket custom InetAddress

Tags: sockets, haskell

I found that [System.Socket.Family.Inet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-0.6.0.1/docs/System-Socket-Family-Inet.html) module doesn't export constructor of [InetAddress](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-0.6.0.1/docs/System-Socket-Family-Inet.html#t:InetAddress). It only exports functions which create a specific addresses. But there is no function which can create a custom one like, for example, `"192.168.1.1"`.

How to create a custom `InetAddress`?

---

#### Note

There are pure functions to work with custom addresses in new [version 0.6.2.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/socket-0.6.2.0):

- `inetAddressFromTuple`
- `inetAddressToTuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal since it runs in the IO-monad, but you can use `getAddressInfo`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import System.Socket
import System.Socket.Family.Inet
import System.Socket.Type.Stream
import System.Socket.Protocol.TCP

test = do (addr:_) <- getAddressInfo (Just "192.168.10.1") Nothing aiNumericHost  :: IO [AddressInfo Inet Stream TCP]
          return $ inetAddress (socketAddress addr)
```

Comment: I don't like dealing with IO here, but I guess it's the only way. Thanks!

Comment: I just added the pure functions `inetAddressFromTuple` and `inetAddressToTuple` to the library. You'll find the new version on Hackage.